# unable to return in node.js from a function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, npm

I have three blocks of code where block one executes first and the result of first block is passed to bloack 2 and then the final result is then passed to the third block which has to send data to the route.
But at the end the return is undefined.

```
function getUserKey(userRole, callback) {


//keys value is stored and returned
                  var keys = base.menuModel.find({ 'name' : userRole  }, function (err, result) {
                                        if (!err) {
                                            var menu =  JSON.stringify(result);
                                              menu = JSON.parse(menu);
                                              var menuKeys = [];
                                              for(i = 0;i < Object.keys(menu[0].permissions[0]).length;i++) {
                                                    menuKeys.push((Object.keys(menu[0].permissions[0])[i]));
                                                  }
                                                callback(null,menuKeys);                   
                //returns menukeys to be shown
                                          }
                                              else {
                                                return err;
                                              }
                                         });

                }
```

n is holding the menu keys

```
                function userMenuData(n, callback) {
                       var filterResult =  base.globalMenuModel.find({"title" : { $in : n}},function (err, result) {
                                              if (!err) {
                                                    callback(null,result);        
                                                     } 
                                              else {
                                                  return err;
                                              }
                                             });
                }

                var userMenu = function(userRole,callback) {
                  var userMenuTemp = async.compose(userMenuData, getUserKey);
            var sendData = userRole is passed and the result is obtained
                    userMenuTemp(userRole,function(err,result) {

                      return result; // data success
                    });
            console.log(sendData);  //undefined
            return sendData;
                }
```

here i want to pass sendData to route in node.js
but at the console i am getting undefined.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It's the async nature of node that's getting you. The console.log is happening before any of those functions are returned. You want to check out a library that does promises like Q http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/